# Why did Stephenie Meyer choose Bree Tanner for a Twilight series novella?

Tags: twilight

> I've never figured out why some of my characters take on strong lives of their own, but I am always happy when they do. Those characters are the most effortless to write, and so their stories are usually the ones that get finished. Bree is one of those characters, and she's the chief reason why this story is now in your hands, rather than lost in the maze of forgotten folders inside my computer.
>   **- *Introduction (Short second life of Bree Tanner)***

Throughout the Twilight series there are many short-lived characters (and I really mean *many*).

Why did the author specifically select Bree Tanner for her Eclipse novella?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is?

Comment: @BrianS - My main concern is that the quote perfectly answers the question, she chose her because she'd already written a few extra paragraphs about her that got cut and was able to recycle that into a novella-length story. She was chosen because the Author wanted to cash in on the success of her previous novel without doing much work.

Comment: Unless Stephanie Meyer is a character in a SciFi work, the "character-motivation" tag is woefully misplaced here

Comment: I will not vote to re-open at this point; OP has pointed out the exact reason why the Author has chosen this character, and then gone and ruled that reason out (leaving only opinion-based answers). Plus the question has not been edited since it was closed...

Comment: Not necessarily opinion based. If the author has stated her reasons somewhere (and the answer given seems to indicate she did), then this is perfectly answerable. Likewise, other parties connected to the author may provide an answer as well (_"as her pubisher, I advised her to ..."_).
Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well here appears to be a answer.

[stepheniemeyer.com](http://stepheniemeyer.com/breetanner.html)

> **I was thinking a lot about the newborns,** imagining their side of the
>   story, and one thing led to another. I started writing from Bree's
>   perspective about those final days, and what it was like to be a
>   newborn.

So from here we can see that she wrote about Bree, because she needed/wanted to write about the newborns. Also, she does write about a lot of female characters. And Bree was very vulnerable. That adds to her appeal as a character. She is:

- Innocent. Bree is young and this shows how the war can take anyone.
- Young and female. The book is YA and Myer has experience writing about young females.
- She is a newborn. Stephanie wanted to write about newborns, so that is why it couldn't have been just anyone.

So, so far she seems to follow all of the criteria.

> Her story is a nice complement to Eclipse; it explains a lot of the
>   things that Bella never knew. So I dusted it off and finished it up
>   for placement in the Guide.

Also, as stated below Bree had a place in the movies so that could be a reason. She had a character that everyone would know, so she didn't have to start at the bottom.

> One of the major benefits of this plan was that it would be out before
>   the movie, so people would get to know Bree before they saw her in the
>   film. That made sense to me, and we decided to go ahead with it.

She needed a character. If the character wasn't Bree it would have been Mary(or someone else) with a similar story line. Myers wouldn't have written about someone who was evil, because that probably wouldn't have held that same appeal to readers. Also, the very violent newborns all were killing each other, the character probably wouldn't have survived or have heard all the stuff that she did, if she wasn't nice and not boisterous. So the character would have had a character type like Bree, probably.

She wanted to portray how Newborns are and how they aren't all evil. That they were just following their nature.

Comment: "...if she wasn't nice and not boisterous."  This is a great answer, but I *still* have no idea what this fragment is supposed to mean.  :)